# Where is the definition of class rqhead in freeBSD?

Tags: c, multithreading, kernel, freebsd

I am trying to change the kernel of freeBSD. There is a class named `rqhead` used in funtcions `runq_choose()` and class `runq`. I'm looking for the first definition of this class which is not defined in the class `runq.h`. Where is the definition of this struct and what is its name?

Comment: ctags and grep are your friend...use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are defined in `sys/runq.h`.

Type `man TAILQ_HEAD` for details explaining the `TAILQ_HEAD(rqhead, thread)` line.